# Tensorflow R-CNN Anchor sizes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/anchor_generators/grid_anchor_generator.py#L168

I've been reading the code for R-CNN model in Tensorflow's examples . 
and i've seen this line .. When we are multiplying the y_centers by the stride which is 16 in default  according to :

```
  if anchor_stride is None:
      anchor_stride = [16, 16]
```

, the feature image height is for example 8  .

How come is the stride larger than the feature image size ? 
this way the y_centers will be out of bounds ..